# is it "put off the meeting to 2 pm" or "put off the meeting until 2pm"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

I was telling my co-worker that we needed to reschedule a meeting. This is what I said:

> I just realized there might be a conflict in my schedule. Can we put off our meeting to 1 PM?

I am not sure if I am using the right preposition here. I wonder if I should use "until" instead of "to" here?

Comment: Both sound natural to my Canadian ears

Comment: Same (American).

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'until' here.

If you put something off that is a continuous action that happens up to the point when the thing happens. When you want to connect a continous action to a point in time you use 'until'.

If you were to use 'rearrange' (or synonyms of) then 'to' would be correct as rearranging is not a continuous action; it is something that you do once at the time.

This link may be helpful: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/until

Comment: Either is valid. English is not very particular about prepositions, and often there are multiple alternatives. If you're setting a new time, then you can use "to"; if you prefer to think of it, as you do, as dragging it over the calendar then "until" may be more natural, but that's just one way of looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

They *basically* mean the same thing – though, to my ear, in different ways:

- > Can we put off our meeting to 1 PM?

  The meeting is postponed, and rescheduled to be at 1 PM.
- > Can we put off our meeting until 1 PM?

  The meeting is postponed for the period from now until 1 PM. After that time, it will no longer be postponed and can – presumably – go ahead.

The distinction is not relevant in this sentence, but it might become relevant if the context is different. For example:

- > Can we put off our meeting until after the match?

  Does not specify exactly when the meeting is, only constraints on when it should be: invites further negotiation.
- > Can we put off our meeting to after the match?

  Proposes a specific time: immediately after the match.